# Best package for heat sinking?

Tags: heatsink, packages

I'm buying a LM317 and it comes in 3 different packages. Which is the best for attaching a heat sink? The options are:

- TO-3
- TO-220
- TO-92

Answer (score 8, accepted):

LM317 in TO-92 only does 100mA, wheras the TO-3 and TO-220 are both 1.5A - so it depends on how much current you need!

"Best for attaching a heat sink" - hard to say. It's easy to attach a TO-220 to a heatsink, just a hole and thermal compound (or one of the clip on ones). You can also just attach them to the PCB for a bit of extra cooling.

T0-3 can have a lower thermal resistance to the heatsink, but generally are more awkward to mount.

TO-92 isn't really possible to attach to a heatsink.

Comment: There are different varieties of LM317, some good for 1A, some for 1.5A. Also, if you're dropping a lot of voltage in the reg, you need to derate it a bit.

Comment: Hey, I've seen heat-sinked TO-92.

Comment: There is a heat sink for almost everything online. now at radio shack, you are out of luck. We have used heat sinks on some weird packages at work.

Answer (score 8):

[Linear publishes this information](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CBcQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.linear.com%2Fdesigntools%2Fpackaging%2FLinear_Technology_Thermal_Resistance_Table.pdf&ei=5LnlTPaZDsP58Ab1t-ChCQ&usg=AFQjCNGZJwO3JZqS9RJQdtfy6Ze3ieLbIA)

\$\theta_{JA}\$:

TO-3: 35°C/W

TO-92: 160°C/W

TO-220: 50°C/W

So the TO-3 wins in \$\theta_{JA}\$, which implies that it would be able to transfer the most heat to a heatsink as well.  Never seen a TO-92 attached to a heatsink, i would thing it would require a lot of support to try to do so.

In terms of physical attachment, the TO-220 and TO-3 are about the same, just a different type of heatsink is needed.  TO-3 would take up more space in most applications.

Several other companies publish similar charts but a quick google-fu didn't turn one up for national, send em an e-mail, I'm sure they have the data somewhere.

Comment: Lowest \$\theta_{JA}\$ doesn't necessarily mean lowest \$\theta_{JHs}\$! Imagine a TO-220 with a 1cm body height. This will have a better \$\theta_{JA}\$, but the \$\theta_{JHs}\$ would be the same.

Comment: TO-3 packages are often mounted on the enclosure, or on a heat sink exposed outside of the case.  [Example.](http://pi-amp.com/Pi-Amp-R5-Build-Log/images/amp1.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

TO-220 would be the easiest/best for attaching a heatsink in your application, I'd suspect